# TypeError Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when getting data from Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to get get some data from an API using React.  Below is one of my components where I am getting the error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Filmcard from "./Filmcard";

const url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=4ababda2";

class Filmcardlist extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      films: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(resonse => resonse.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ films: data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("I have errored" + error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.films.map(film => (
          <Filmcard
            Title={film.Title}
            Year={film.Year}
            imdbID={film.imdbID}
            Type={film.Type}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Filmcardlist;
```

I am fairly new to React and I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```js
this.setState({ films: data });
```

to:

```js
this.setState({ films: data.Search });
```

and `this.props.films` to `this.state.films` in render function.

Comment: unfortunately this does not render anything and nothing is appearing the film array.

Comment: Are you sure theres valid array in `data` from fetch response ?

Comment: in the JSON response there is an array called "Search". I have changed {films: data} to {films: Search}  . This does not work. It is saying Search is undefined.

Comment: Response is a nested array in a object.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not return anything.

Comment: Console log error says ```I have erroredTypeError: Failed to fetch ```

Comment: I needed to add "s" to the http ```http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=4ababda2``` Thanks for all your help Qiarah

Answer (score -1):

Just change props with **state** and as I read the comments you need to map data.search.
Try this code, hope I helped!

```
{
if(this.state && this.state.films && this.state.films.search){
this.state.films.search.map(film => (
      <Filmcard
        Title={film.Title}
        Year={film.Year}
        imdbID={film.imdbID}
        Type={film.Type}
      />
    ))}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is giving me a syntax error on this line ```if (this.state && this.state.films && this.state.films.search)```